# Write Windows batch script to duplicate folder with date appended as new file name

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a windows batch script that allows me to duplicate a directory [foldername] with a new file name with date appended to it [foldername.date01]. But it should also check if a duplicate has already been made for current date and create a new one like [foldername.date02] and so on..

xcopy /s/e c:\source d:\target

allows me to copy but I dont know how to retrieve date and append it.

Comment: What to do if there is already a folder with the current date appended, should the new name then contain an even more current date?? Please specify what to do exactly in case of duplicates! Furthermore, share what you have tried on your own, because SO is not a free code writing service! Check out the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) pages and learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: I think, date_time format will work for him.

Comment: I do not have any batch programming knowledge. I am doing this manually. And I already shared what I could came up with. looking at the answer below it seems I underestimated the code. it look much more complex than I thought it would be. Any format will work as long as I can differentiate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will backup your directory structure to another drive with all copied folders named *SourceFolderName_CurrentDate_BackupTime*. Let me know, if any errors:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "source=C:\Source" & SET "target=D:\Target"
FOR /F %%a IN ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| FIND "."') DO SET DTS=%%a  
SET DT=%DTS:~0,8%_%DTS:~8,6%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('DIR /b /a:d "%source%"') DO (
        XCOPY /s/e/y/b/q/r/k/i "%source%\%%G" "%target%\%%G_%DT%" )
EXIT /B
```

Note, *wmic* is supported starting from WinXP Pro, and the above *wmic* command outputs OS locale independent time stamp. You can adjust `DT` variable format in its SET statement as you wish.

Comment: @keanu101 What Windows version do you use? What exact error is posted? Your above comment is as deficient as your question, without providing any details at all.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 Pro. I did not see any error so far.

Comment: Let me try this one line at a time instead of running the whole script and see what might be the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119005/discussion-between-keanu101-and-sambul35).

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed. That will save me so much time.

Comment: @keanu101 Now that you have the answer, consider editing your Question to make it more clear for others, as apparently some users marked it unclear. It doesn't mean of course adding totally different requirements set. :)

Comment: for using `wmic` to get a locale independent date and time +1